# 64GB Debian 8 Server, Do I need SSD?

Tags: performance, nginx, ssd

I have a Debian 8 server with following config:

```
Quad Core E3-1270v5
64GB RAM
2x4TB SATA Disks
```

The server uses nginx 1.10 and redis to deliver files to clients. My question is since newrelic shows my RAM utilization to be only 10% will using a SSD for the OS improve performance (faster processing) for user?

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If there are lots of random accesses to the data and the size of the working set exceeds the amount of RAM you can devote to caching, then yes, using an SSD for the data (not for the OS) would improve performance.

Look at `iostat -x 3 /dev/sd?` while the system is under peak load to get an idea of how heavily utilized your disks are. If there is next to no activity (at most a few requests per second, with `%util` under 10%), then an SSD probably wouldn't help much. If `%util` is over 50%, or `svctm` is in the hundreds or higher, then an SSD would probably help.